# How to pass HTML elements through res.render?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm using Node.js with EJS templates and I'm having trouble passing through html elements through res.render, I tried to pass it in as a string but it ended up not working because of the escape characters HTML has. I use mongoose to search through the database given the parameters in the URL as an ID, and pass an HTML string that is saved in the database. After, I try to convert the HTML string into valid HTML by using parseFromString in the actual HTML page.

**Blog.js file, exporting as a router and being used in app.js as a route.**

```
const express = require("express");
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const router = express.Router();

const Blog = require("../database/Blog.js");
const User = require("../database/User.js");

router.get("/category/:category", (req, res)=>{
  console.log("Hello");
  console.log(req.params);
})

router.get("/blog/:id", (req, res)=>{
  Blog.find({_id: req.params.id}).then(arrayOfDocuments=>{
    if (arrayOfDocuments.length > 0){

      const htmlString = arrayOfDocuments[0].htmlContent;
      //const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM(htmlString);

      res.render("BlogPage", {metaDetails: {title: arrayOfDocuments[0].title}, htmlBody: htmlString});
    }else{
      res.render("Error");
    }
  })
})

router.get("/playground", (req, res)=>{
  res.render("Blog", {metaDetails: {}});
})


module.exports = router;
```

***Actual HTML Page:***

```
<%- include("Header") -%>
  <script>
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const html = parser.parseFromString("<%=htmlBody%>", "text/html");
    const body = html.body;
    document.body.appendChild(body);
  </script>
<%- include("Footer") -%>
```

**This is what happens to the function when looking at the source page:**

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const html = parser.parseFromString("  &lt;div class=&#34;blog-container&#34;&gt;
  &lt;div class=&#34;intro&#34;&gt;
    &lt;h1 class=&#34;title-intro&#34;&gt;
      A Comprehensive Review of the Nosler 21 Hunting Rifle: The Ultimate Companion for Hunters
    &lt;/h1&gt;
    &lt;div class=&#34;page-information&#34;&gt;
      &lt;p&gt;&lt;i class=&#34;fa-regular fa-clock&#34;&gt;&lt;/i&gt; 5 min read&lt;/p&gt;
      &lt;a href=&#34;/people/2oad022dam&#34;&gt;By Jacob Delp&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;img alt=&#34;Nosler 21 Gun&#34; src=&#34;https://www.outdoorlife.com/uploads/2021/07/29/DSCF8306.jpg?auto=webp&#34;/&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;

  &lt;div class=&#34;accordion&#34; id=&#34;accordionExample&#34;&gt;
      &lt;div class=&#34;accordion-item&#34;&gt;
        &lt;h2 class=&#34;accordion-header&#34;&gt;
          &lt;button class=&#34;accordion-button&#34; type=&#34;button&#34; data-bs-toggle=&#34;collapse&#34; data-bs-target=&#34;#collapseOne&#34; aria-expanded=&#34;true&#34; aria-controls=&#34;collapseOne&#34;&gt;
            Table of Contents
          &lt;/button&gt;
        &lt;/h2&gt;
        &lt;div id=&#34;collapseOne&#34; class=&#34;accordion-collapse collapse show&#34; data-bs-parent=&#34;#accordionExample&#34;&gt;
          &lt;div class=&#34;accordion-body&#34;&gt;
            &lt;a href=&#34;#introduction&#34;&gt;1. Intro&lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;a href=&#34;#caliber-options&#34;&gt;2. Caliber Options&lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;a href=&#34;#accuracy-and-precision&#34;&gt;3. Accuracy and Precision&lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;a href=&#34;#construction-and-optics-compability&#34;&gt;4. Construction and Optics Compability&lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;a href=&#34;#use-cases-and-benefits&#34;&gt;5. Use Cases and Benefits&lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;a href=&#34;#pricing&#34;&gt;6. Pricing&lt;/a&gt;
          &lt;/div&gt;
        &lt;/div&gt;
      &lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;


  &lt;div class=&#34;paragraph-segment&#34; id=&#34;introduction&#34;&gt;
      &lt;h2&gt;The Nosler 21&lt;/h2&gt;
      &lt;p&gt;
        Welcome to our detailed review of the
        Nosler 21 Hunting Rifle. This rifle is
        a reliable and versatile firearm that is
        sure to enhance your hunting experience.
      &lt;/p&gt;

      &lt;p&gt;
        In this article, we will explore the key
        features, specifications, use cases, and
        pricing information of this exceptional
        hunting rifle.
      &lt;/p&gt;
      &lt;p&gt;Let&#39;s dive right in!&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;
```

A lot of other HTML characters are present that weren't present inside the HTML string saved inside Mongoose. What do I do?

Comment: try `"<%-htmlBody%>"`. `<%-` scriptlet tag outputs unescaped HTML string, `<%=` escaped, which is what you have rendered

Comment: how does `htmlString` string look like when you get it from the database, try logging it on the server before outputting it into template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When outputting `htmlBody` in the template, try using `<%-` scriptlet tag, which outputs unescaped HTML string; `<%=` outputs escaped.

Try this:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const html = parser.parseFromString('<%-htmlBody%>', "text/html");
const body = html.body;
document.body.appendChild(body.firstElementChild);
```

Comment: This solution does not work, but your use of <%-%> instead of <%=%> helped me fix the problem. I sent over the html as a string, and sent <%-htmlBody%> which fixed the problem! Thank you.

Comment: you mean instead of `'<%-htmlBody%>'` you used `<%-htmlBody%>`, without quotes? Also, append `body.firstElementChild`, because you'll have child body element..